# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in kochava using Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
error - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
C:\xampp\htdocs\next-contv-web\node_modules\kochava\dist\kochava.js:17
import { Log } from "./utils/log";

react JS version being used: "react": "17.0.2"
next JS version: "12",
kochava version being used:  "kochava": "^3.0.4"
```

Getting the above error msg when installed the kochava latest version in next/react (web sdk). Need help to resolve this issue.

Getting the below error after adding "type":"module" in the package.json of kochava and running the app again:

```
error - Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\xampp\htdocs\next-contv-web\node_modules\kochava\dist\utils\log' imported from C:\xampp\htdocs\next-contv-web\node_modules\kochava\dist\kochava.js
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\xampp\htdocs\next-contv-web\node_modules\kochava\dist\utils\log' imported from C:\xampp\htdocs\next-contv-web\node_modules\kochava\dist\kochava.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:437:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1009:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1218:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:580:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:294:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:80:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  page: '/'
}
```

Comment: https://support.kochava.com/web-sdk-integration/react-web-sdk-integration/ --> following this documentation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.